# Why am I getting this error with add_patch()?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create a rectangle that will cover the extremas of my graphs. 'peak_index' is the location of the peaks, and they will mark the peaks with 'x'. However, I would like to create shaded rectangles around them to show tolerances for my project. However, I keep getting this error. I will show the part of my code producing the error below. I tried re-installing the libraries, using '.gcaadd_patch(), and not using the list of left,bottom, etc. Nothing works, so I guess I don't understand the issue. Can yall help?

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 15))

    ax[0].plot(plot_data.index, vlwf, color='green', label='VLWf')
    ax[0].set_title('Vertical Load Waveform')
    ax[0].set_ylabel('N')
    ax[0].plot(plot_data.index, iso_max, color='red', label='ISO Max')
    ax[0].plot(plot_data.index, iso_min, color='red', label='ISO Min')
    ax[0].legend()
    ax[0].plot(peak_index, vlwf[peak_index], "x")
    ax[0].plot(axoccur_concern, vlwf[axoccur_concern], "o", color='red')
    ax_zero = ax[0]
    for i in peak_index:
        left, bottom, width, height = (i-30,vlwf[peak_index]-0.05*vlwf[peak_index]-0.05, 60, vlwf[peak_index]+0.05*vlwf[peak_index]-0.05)
        rect = mpatches.Rectangle((left,bottom),width,height, 
                                  alpha = 0.1,
                                  facecolor = 'red')
        ax_zero.add_patch(rect)
```

Comment: Could you create a fully reproducible example?  And the full error trace?  With the given code there doesn't seem to be a reason for the mentioned error, except if `vlwf` would be an integer.  Also note that if `peak_index` is an array (or a list), `vlwf[peak_index]` doesn't make much sense to calculate the bottom of the rectangle.  Maybe you want `vlwf[i]`?  Anyway, without additional information, answering your question would be a blind guessing game.

Comment: @JohanC thank you for your response. I will on getting a reproducable example to you today. There is much data analysis, like 400 lines of code, I need to spend some time doing it

Comment: @JohanC HEY! I replaced vlwf[peak_index] with vlwf[i] and IT WORKS. Looking at it now, I am surprised that I didn't catch that. THANK YOU!!!!